# Which OAuth2 grant type is appropriate for background job processing?

Tags: oauth2, grant-login-access

If I want my application to process jobs and send API REST requests to my APEX endpoints, which OAuth2 authorization/grant method should I use?

- If I use authorization_code, then the browser needs to redirect (to Salesforce login page) and the user needs to confirm access. (This would be wrong right?).

I think that I would want to use `grant_type` : **password**

If I use password, then I can just set my organizations administration username and password in my application and use that.

I plan on batching up some requests and sending through gearman as a background process.

Answer (score 2):

I solved with this approach:

1. use grant_type = authorization_code the first time and
   ACCESS_TYPE=offline.
2. save the AccesToken and the RefreshToken in a
   custom setting.
3. Start the background job and everytime the job
   starts, ask for a new token using the refresh token and grant_type =
   refresh_token.

You have all the documentation in google to do this.
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer?hl=es
Look for "Using a refresh token"

Comment: If you save the token, do you also save the instance URL that you should be using to send your REST requests?